# split multiple columns by separator pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to split every column by ":", using pandas

```
    ,0,1,2,3,4
0,MMSI : 222111345,Country : Singa,Ship name : xxxVessel,Call sign : abcd,IMO number : 12345
1,MMSI : 222111345,Country : Singa,Ship name : xxxVessel,Call sign : abcd,IMO number : 12345
2,MMSI : 222111345,Country : Singa,Ship name : xxxVessel,Call sign : abcd,IMO number : 12345
3,MMSI : 222111345,Country : Singa,Ship name : xxxVessel,Call sign : abcd,IMO number : 12345
```

I tryed
`df3 = df3[df3.columns[0]].str.split(":",expand=True)` but doesn´t work

Comment: Why dont you use separator as `df = pd.read_csv("test_data1", header=None, sep=":")` while you reading the file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try via `concat()` and list comprehension:

```
df=pd.concat([df3[x].str.split(':',expand=True) for x in df3],axis=1)
```

**Note:** If there are integer and float values in columns then:

```
cols=df3.columns[df3.dtypes=='O']
#Filtered out columns that are of type Object    
df=pd.concat([df3[x].str.split(':',expand=True) for x in cols],axis=1)
```

**Note:**

If you are reading csv file then you can also try this :

```
df3=pd.read_csv("filename.csv", sep=",|:").reset_index()
```